# how to build watsapp like chat application in android

Tags: android, chat

Please suggest way to build watsapp like chat application.

In My Android application i have to put Chat Functionality

I already knows following ways.

1. Chat application by using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging).
2. Socket Programing
3. By using our webservice

Is there any other techniques for chatting app?

Comment: you can use asmack smack version for android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various methods to develop chat application.

1) Using `HTTP` connection (In this method each and everytime you want to send message, you have to call the webservice and for receive message, you continously need to call the webservice using Timer).

2) Using `XMPP` Server (`XMPP` server uses Socket programming, so once a connection will be establish, then it uses that connection each and everytime, you no need to create connection everytime, like `HTTP`).

3) Using `GCM` (Using Push Notification you can send and receive messages as well).

Comment: Please Suggest me. What is the best way from this three?                                                                 if i will go with first way. i continously need to call the webservice using Timer. i think it will consume so much internet data

Comment: @MiralBhalani yes you are right, it will take a little time as well as it consumes more Internet Data. Best way is using XMPP for my point of view

Answer (score 2):

Things you need to build a chat app:

1. Server:
   This is required to store all the user information like username, password and gcm registration id (will come to this later).
   You can host it anywhere Amazon EC2, Google App Engine, etc
   APIs for login, chat message sending, message list, delete message and many others.
2. Registration for GCM push notification:
   Refer the link below:
   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-server-to-send-push-notifications-with-gcm-to-android-devices-using-python
3. Android:
   Register to GCM and send the gcm registration id(as mentioned in point 1) to the server for updating.
   Design user interface to send message, sending a message can be done either through REST API or by using socket connection.
   You can explore XMPP and MQTT.
4. Server to Device communication and vice versa:
   Now, on receiving message coming from the device, publish the message to the socket connection and as a fallback send push notification to the receiver device. There are 2 ways to do it:
   i) Send the message payload along with the push notification
   ii) Only send "sync" and on receiving the "sync" notification, receiver's android app can make a call to the server, fetch all the messages and show it to the user. Benefit of this approach is that the messages will never be lost. You will have to maintain the "sync" timing on the android app side.

Above was the normal way to build it if you want to learn but if you want to just get it done fast then you can integrate [Applozic Mobile & Web Chat Libraries](https://www.applozic.com) which will get you started with chat within half an hour. And the beauty is you wouldn't even need to develop or host any server.

Sample code to build chat in available in Github:
Android Chat SDK https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK

Web Chat Plugin https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Web-Plugin

iOS Chat SDK https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-iOS-SDK

PS: I am the Cofounder @Applozic